# A question in vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let 
$$ \vec{a} = a_1\hat{i} + a_2\hat{j} + a_3\hat{k} \\
  \vec{b} = b_1\hat{i} + b_2\hat{j} + b_3\hat{k} \\ \vec{c} = c_1\hat{i} + c_2\hat{j} + c_3\hat{k}$$

be $3$ non zero vectors such that:

1. $|\vec{c}| = 1$
2. angle between $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ is $\pi/4$
3. $\vec{c}$ is perpendicular to $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$

If $ [\vec{a} \vec{b} \vec{c}]^2 = \lambda(a_1^2 + a_2^2 + a_3^2)(b_1^2 + b_2^2 + b_3^2) $, what is $ \lambda $?

**MY ATTEMPTS/IDEAS**:

Obviously, $\vec{c}$ is parallel to $\vec{a} \times \vec{b}$. Also, $(a_1^2 + a_2^2 + a_3^2)(b_1^2 + b_2^2 + b_3^2) = 1/2(\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b})^2$

I don't know how to use these results (along with the first condition) to evaluate the box product. Hints?

Comment: Btw, I couldn't help putting such a vague title as there's a lot of detail in the question which couldn't have been summarised in the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the following, big dots denote dot products of vectors, and small dots denote ordinary multiplication of numbers (scalars).

Since $\vec{c}$ is a unit vector that's perpendicular to both $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$, we have
$$
\vec{a} \times \vec{b} = \Vert \vec{a} \Vert \cdot \Vert \vec{b} \Vert \sin \frac{\pi}4
\cdot \vec{c} = \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\Vert \vec{a} \Vert \cdot \Vert \vec{b} \Vert 
\cdot \vec{c}
$$
Taking the dot product with $\vec{c}$, and using the fact that $\Vert \vec{c} \Vert = 1$, we get
$$
(\vec{a} \times \vec{b}) \bullet \vec{c} = 
\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\Vert \vec{a} \Vert \cdot \Vert \vec{b} \Vert 
\cdot (\vec{c} \bullet \vec{c}) = \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\Vert \vec{a} \Vert \cdot \Vert \vec{b} \Vert 
$$
Squaring both sides gives 
$$
[abc]^2 =
\left\{(\vec{a} \times \vec{b}) \bullet \vec{c}\right\}^2 = 
\frac{1}{2}\Vert \vec{a} \Vert^2 \cdot \Vert \vec{b} \Vert^2
$$
so $\lambda = \tfrac12$.

Comment: Everthing's fine and I got the solution too, but there's a small problem. The first line opens up as a vector and then it suddenly becomes a scalar.

Comment: @Parth Thakkar: don't confuse the _dot product of two vectors_ for the _product of a vector by a scalar_. Because here both are represented by $\cdot \,$, you have to see the context.

Comment: Yes, sorry about the abuse of the "dot". The right-hand side of the first line is indeed a vector -- it's the product of three scalars times the vector $\vec{c}$.

Comment: I fixed the dot problem

Comment: That's not what I was telling. What I am saying is $ \vec{a} \times \vec{b} = \Vert \vec{a} \Vert \cdot \Vert \vec{b} \Vert \sin \frac{\pi}4
\cdot \vec{c} = \ldots$

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't see your point. All three expressions in the first line are vectors.